# Next JS conditional styles not applying

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

```
<label className={`${darkModeActive ? 'text-brand-five' : 'text-brand-seven'} ${errors.invoiceDate ? 'text-[#EC5756]' : ''}`} htmlFor="invoiceDate">
   Invoice Date
</label>
```

I am trying to apply this red text when errors.InvoiceDate is true, i can see that the class does get applied to the DOM but the text color does not change, I'm not sure if it's the other classes clashing with it? Funny enough if i change the color and save the file it will work... but then restarting the dev server the same thing happens. Is there a better way do do this?

Comment: I am not sure enough but you can try `${errors.invoiceDate ? 'text-[#EC5756] !important' : ''}`

Comment: share all of file codes for better answers

Answer (score 1):

You should only have a single class that applies the same property with the same variant at the same time. Assuming both `text-brand-five` and `text-brand-seven` apply `color`, then they may be overriding the `text-[#EC5756]` class.

Consider only having one of these classes applied to the element at any one time, like:

```
let color = 'text-brand-seven';
if (darkModeActive) {
  color = 'text-brand-five';
} elseif (errors.invoiceDate) {
  color = 'text-[#EC5756]';
}

<label className={color} htmlFor="invoiceDate">
```